# how do i convert results to list python

Tags: python, list, definition

I have this code I'm trying to run by using two columns of a csv file that I've converted into lists and used those lists to get a < and > comparison between the numbers inside, now i want to get the results from this comparison in a list format of multiple lists that I want to display in an interval of six digits(the results) per list

eg I get

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12

and  i want  to display this as

[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[7,8,9,10,11,12]

this is the code I'm using for comparing the lists

```
'''
    for i in range(len(fsa)):
        if fsa[i] < ghf[i]:
            print('1')
        else:
            print('0') 
'''
```

the code that's not working which is the one for showing results in an intervalled list format is this one

```
'''
print()
start = 0
end = len(''' i want the length of my results from the previous code, the 1's and 0's here. ''')
for x in range(start,end,6):
    print('''i want the results here as my list'''[x:x+6])
'''
```

I'm a beginner, please help, how do i make the results a list?

Comment: Code seems to be working on my machine. What exactly is the output you are seeing?

Comment: I want to make the results I get from the first code (the one for comparing the elements in  my lists) into a list. i don't want to get the data in the "fsa" in list form, i want the results in a list format....How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to make a new list and append it instead of print.

```
...
...
temp = []
for x in range(start,end,6):
    temp.append(fsa[x:x+6])
    
print(temp)
#[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

i got the answer i wanted. Incase someone else was suffering with this as
well here's my solution

```
'''
kol = []
for i in range(len(fsa)):
    if fsa[i] < ghf[i]:
        kol.append('1')
    else:
        kol.append('0')


start = 0
end = len(fsa)
for x in range(start,end,6):
    print(kol[x:x+6])
'''
```

outcome

```
'''
    ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1']
    ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0']
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
    ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1']
'''
```